# Selenium python get_attribute() return the actual data of the image and not the link

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to code a script that downloads some images from google images, but when I try to get the attribute 'src' from the image it returns the data of the image and not the link. If I wait enough time, only the first actually works.
I found someone with a similar problem and they suggested him to use a wait, but its not working for me.
This is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ricerca = input("Dimmi cosa vuoi cercare:")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('c:\se\chromedriver.exe')
page = driver.get('https://www.google.com/images')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

search.send_keys(ricerca)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

div1 = driver.find_element_by_id('islrg')
print(div1)

imglist = div1.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
c = 0

for x in imglist[0:10]:
    att = x.get_attribute('class')
    if att =='wXeWr islib nfEiy mM5pbd':
        x.click()

        link = x.get_attribute('href')
        src1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "n3VNCb")))

        time.sleep(120)

        src = driver.find_element_by_class_name('n3VNCb').get_attribute('src')
                                             
        r = requests.get(src)
        f = open(ricerca+'('+str(c)+').png','wb')
        f.write(r.content)
        f.close

        c = c + 1

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way to find images will only result in 1 image. `n3VNCb` is the class name only for the image in right side after you click onto any result. That's why even if you wait more time, nothing will happen.

If you already use explicit wait `EC.presence_of_element_located`, you don't need `time.sleep`.

If you want to get all result images on the page, use this xpath: `//img[@class="rg_i Q4LuWd"]`

Try:

```py
import urllib
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[@class="rg_i Q4LuWd"]')
for elem in elements:
    link = elem.get_attribute('src')
    urllib.urlretrieve(link, "img.png")
```

I haven't tested yet, but you can use this example to make it work. Just a note that the image that you download is not high res, it's cache from Google. If you need higher res image, you need to dig more :).

Comment: Thanks man i'll try later
Anyway i tought that my code actually click on every image, so looking for class will result in one image but its repeated for more links
(im very sorry if i make mistakes in english but um not a native speaker)

Comment: Ah about the clicking image, I think there might be logic problem in your code, so it only clicks once. Try: `imglist = find_elements_by_xpath('//img[@class="rg_i Q4LuWd"]')`